Can we create artificial pressure zones with extreme pressure differences simultaneously without a container?
I understand the basics of air pressure and convection, but there's a few things I don't quite understand. And I know that pressure can exist within a container, and I know that pressure is all over the earth, but is it possible to create artificial pressure diffrences?
Let's say that I wanted to heat the air in front of me, and cool the air behind me at the same time, outside of a container. Theoretically, the hot air (low pressure) would rise up due to convection, and the cold air (high pressure) would move towards the emptied space where the hot air was. But how would we heat and cool the air at the same time, without a container?

Why do you think a container is needed to heat and cool air?

A Peltier cooler would do exactly this

The regions of air you are trying to heat and cool are spatially separated, so there's no reason you can't put a heat source (e.g. a candle) where you want to heat up the air or a heat sink (e.g. ice) where you want to cool it. Either by itself is sufficient to establish convection. Land and sea breeze occur in the open world.
For extreme pressure differences, you would need larger and larger temperature gradients. Since pressure gradients are sound and sound disperses, there is limit to how much of a pressure difference you can generate without creating a shock. In this regard, your question is pretty open ended.

With explosives strong enough to create supersonic shock waves.
